# Yii2 how to use pjax to submit a form without closing bootstrap modal popup

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using bootstrap modal for login page. If i submit the form in popup will be closed and shown response. But instead of closing popup, would like to display response in same popup window. Could anyone help me without closing the popup to show the response data.

Sample View Page:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= Html::beginForm(['site/login'], 'post'); ?>
<?= Html::input('text', 'email', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= Html::input('text', 'password', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'name' => 'login']) ?>
<?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

In Controller

```
if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {

     $authenticateUser = $model->login();
     if($authenticateUser == "Locked"){
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('invalid', 'Your account has been locked. Please contact customer service for assistance');
                return $this->redirect('index');
     }else{
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Successfully logged in');
                 return $this->redirect('index');
     }
}
```

In Controller, Instead of **redirect** ,i've tried with **renderAjax** also. But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce form submission via ajax by adding your own javascript handler `beforeSubmit`. See [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69969-yii2-ajax-submit/page__view__findpost__p__296693).

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?php 
      $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'form-id',                   
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal','data-pjax' => true],
      ]);  
    ?>
        // Your fields
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```